# passing url as hashmaps in backbone route?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm trying to pass a directory location and the file path as part of the hashmaps in backbone routes. This is the url with hashmaps:

```
localhost/index.html#directory-http://localhost/foobar-html/foo.html
```

and this is what my route that maps the above url:

```
routes: {
    'directory-*directoryPath-*filePath': 'render'
},

render: function (directoryPath, filePath) {
    // I get the entire url in directoryPath variable
    // http://localhost/foobar-html/foo.html
    // and filePath is empty.
}
```

What would be the right way to map such type of hash URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes):

> Routes can contain parameter parts, `:param`, which match a single URL component between slashes; and splat parts `*splat`, which can match any number of URL components.

Your problem is that a splat eats up everything so having two splats in one route is pointless; you can't use a parameter part, `:x`, because that stops at a slash.

There are a few things you can do.

1. You could URI encode the slashes in link and use parameter parts. The URL would look like this:

   ```
   #directory-http:%2f%2flocalhost%2ffoobar-html%2ffoo.html
   ```

   and the router would be like this:

   ```
   routes: {
       'directory-:directoryPath-:filePath': 'render'
   },
   render: function(d, f) {
       d = decodeURIComponent(d);
       f = decodeURIComponent(f);
       //...
   }
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xBnaN/
2. You could add your route as a regex using [`route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route), that would give you more freedom in how you construct the pattern. For example, a fragment like this:

   ```
   #directory-http://localhost/foobar-html/foo.html
   ```

   could be handled with a router like this:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       this.route(/directory-(.*?)-(.*)/, 'render');
   },
   render: function(d, f) {
       //...
   }
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/r8MBb/

The second option will run into problems with you inevitably get a `-` inside your `directoryPath` or `filePath`; you could URI encode embedded `-`s to get them through the first option though.